# Exception when launching VB.Net WinForms program

Tags: vb.net, winforms, exception

This program works flawlessly on my own machine - programs always work on the dev machine, right?

It seems to be getting upset upon launch.  The application has 2 forms.  The default form checks to see if there is a /buy command line paramater, and if that is true then it switches to the other form by showing the other form [formSB_Buy.Show()] and hiding itself [Me.Hide()].

This application will only be run from a toolbar which will have a /sell or /buy as a single command line argument.  It only checks for /buy, so anything else would simply proceed to using the default form.  Any assistance to resolve this error would be much appreciated - I'm not sure what to do to resolve it.

The Exception:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Array.InternalGetReference(Void* elemRef, Int32 rank, Int32* pIndices)
   at System.Array.GetValue(Int32 index)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.GetArrayValue(Object[] Indices)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.InternalLateIndexGet(Object Instance, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Boolean ReportErrors, ResolutionFailure& Failure, Boolean[] CopyBack)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ObjectLateInvokeDefault(Object Instance, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Boolean ReportErrors, Boolean[] CopyBack)
   at SellBuy.formSB_Sell.formSB_Sell_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnShown(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CallShownEvent()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
```

The Code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class formSB_Sell

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub

Private Sub formSB_Sell_Shown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    Dim CommandLineArgs As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String) = My.Application.CommandLineArgs
    If CommandLineArgs(0) = "/buy" Then
        formSB_Buy.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        Dim GMResult As String
        Dim wholeline As String = Nothing
        Dim arTextlines As Array
        Dim arLinefields As Array
        ' Load the arTextlines array with the result of the profiles request
        GMResult = GetMacro("&profiles.schwab..4")
        'TextBox129.Text = GMResult
        arTextlines = GMResult.Split(vbNewLine)
        ' Load the arLinefields array with the field data of the current arTextline
        For x = 0 To arTextlines.Length - 1
            arLinefields = Split(arTextlines(x), vbTab)
            For y = 0 To arLinefields.Length - 1
                wholeline = wholeline & Trim(arLinefields(y)) & " : "
            Next y
            Me.comboSBSell_ClientName.Items.Add(arLinefields(1) & " " & arLinefields(3))
            wholeline = Nothing
        Next x
        Me.comboSBSell_ClientName.SelectedIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: just a guess...are you certain you're passing and it's reading a command line param? Can you add a msgbox for CommandLineArgs.length and see if it's 1?

Comment: It's an array index out of bounds error from within `formSB_Sell_Shown`.  Which specific line throws the exception?  What is the size of the array being referenced at that time?  What is the index value attempting to reference it at that time?  Either the runtime environment isn't providing the data/state it needs to, or you need to add some bounds checking code to handle situations where the data/state is different from what is expected.

Comment: @ChaseRocker If `CommandLineArgs.Count = 0`, the error is ArgumentOutOfRangeException. He's getting an IndexOutOfRangeException. His problem lies in `arLinefields` or `arTextlines`.

Comment: possibly nothing was added to `Me.comboSBSell_ClientName` so `Me.comboSBSell_ClientName.SelectedIndex = 0` is throwing the error

Comment: Another possibility is `Items.Add(arLinefields(1) & " " & arLinefields(3))`. I bet that's where the bug is. I could be wrong. If you check the stack trace from OP, it says System.Array is where the error is thrown. And SelectedIndex doesn't throw IndexOutOfRange, but it does throw ArgumentOutOfRange. src: msdn

Comment: ^ Can't edit my comment after 5 minutes. src: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @ChaseRocker when I try to place that in a message box, I get the error: 'length' is not a member of 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)'.    *However I can use the Count property and predictably get a 1 or a 0 by adding or removing the command line parameter from the debug settings.    The Me.comboSBSell_ClientName control was populated, but I could probably still check it before referencing it.  I can get it to blow up by having no command line parameter.  Is it possible that the parameter is failing to pass on the target machine, and if so how/why?

Comment: Thank you all for coming to my aid - I am working through all of your suggestions and observations and will respond to all of you as I process all you have said.  I'm still using your guidance to resolve this issue and will still be responding to the comments you have taken the time to provide.

Comment: Why don't you just tell us in which line you get the error ?

Comment: @Creator The error does not occur at all in the development environment, only on the executable and not at all on my machine, just the machine that will be running the program.  No line is specified in the error.

Comment: @scottyeatscode I was able to pull some maneuvers to force an error on the `Items.Add(arLinefields(1) & " " & arLinefields(3))` line, so I'll add bounds checking there.  It's progress, thanks!

Comment: @RickJohnson I do recommend using List(Of String) instead of System.Array though. You don't have to ReDim or Array.Resize() them because they're essentially super versatile dynamic arrays. You should still do bounds checking anytime you're accessing an index.

Comment: @scottyeatscode When I search for the term System.Array across the entire project, no results are found.  That must be something present in the compiled code only.  The error I posted was  seen when executing the compiled code.  Thanks for the tip for bounds checking with indices!

Comment: @RickJohnson `arTextlines` and `arLinefields` are both of type System.Array.

Comment: @RickJohnson [[here is a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Z9imJxNt)] of me recreating the error. Notice that your stack trace and mine are nearly identical. I've seen this error way too many times. :]

Comment: @scottyeatscode I see.  The "Array" class is "System.Array" by definition.  Thanks!  The last time I coded in VB it was in in VB6, and prior to that good old MS BASIC, I don't recall lists being a structure then.  Next time something calls for what I would use an array for I will consider approaching that with a list instead.